# Floating input element to the right

Tags: html, css

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .header {
        background: #009FC7;
        margin-left: 0px;
        color: white;


    }
    .header a {
        color: white;
    }
    .header h1 {
        margin: 0 0 0 15px;
        font-size: 50px;

    }
    .header h3 {
        margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    }
    .header a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .search {
        float: right;
    }


    </style>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title here</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1>
        <a href="#">Larger heading</a>
    </h1>
    <h3>Smaller heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
        <input value="Google" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
    </div>


    </body>



    </html>
```

I'm trying to position the search bar to the right but in the same line as the header. I've tried floating but it is not working. The search bar is floated to the right but I want to push it up to be in line with "Larger heading".

Comment: I tried putting the header and the search bar inside a bigger div, and that seemed to work. I want to know if I can do it without using an extra wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

You can get by using `display:inline-block`

Css changes

```
.header h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;    /*Added*/
}
.search {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;        /*Added*/
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.header {
  background: #009FC7;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.header a {
  color: white;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header h3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>
    <a href="#">Larger heading</a>
</h1>
  <div class="search">
<input value="Google" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
  </div>
  <h3>Smaller heading</h3>
</div>
```

You can get it by using `flex` also

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.header {
  background: #009FC7;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.header a {
  color: white;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.header h3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Added Css Part*/

.search {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="box">     <!-- Added div -->
    <h1>
      <a href="#">Larger heading</a>
    </h1>
    <div class="search">
      <input value="Google" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Smaller heading</h3>
</div>
```

`display:table` doing the same.

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.header {
  background: #009FC7;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.header a {
  color: white;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: table-cell; /*Added*/
}

.header h3 {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
  display: table-cell;  /*Added*/
  text-align: right;    /*Added*/
  vertical-align: middle;  /*Added*/
}

.box {
  display: table; /*Added*/
  width: 100%;  /*Added*/
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="box">      <!-- Added div -->
    <h1>
      <a href="#">Larger heading</a>
    </h1>
    <div class="search">
      <input value="Google" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Smaller heading</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please upvote/accept answer if it will work so the answer will help other community members.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.header {
    background: #009FC7;
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: white;


}
.header a {
    color: white;
}
.header h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    font-size: 50px;
    float:left; width:70%;
}
.header h3 {
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}
.header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.search {
    float: right;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Title here</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
<h1>
    <a href="#">Larger heading</a>
</h1>
<div class="search">
        <input value="Google" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="gsearch" id="gsearch">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<h3>Smaller heading</h3>

</div>


</body>



</html>
```